# Updating tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, updatepanel

I have tablelayoutpanel on a splitcontainer panel, which is dynamically filled components at runtime. Components have a minimum size and DockStyle is Fill. On resize event i remap the column and row styles, but it does not give the desired result (table cells become smaller than the size of the components and when the number of components of the cell size does not accept the minimum amount of components). The problem is that it is not known in advance how many rows will be. How to properly update tablelayoutpanel????

Comment: Will this help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1487273/763026

Comment: I still do, but it is not working when I change the number of components at runtime